# Error "Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided" when uploading file

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, servlet-3.0, tomcat8

I am trying to upload an file via a form in a JSP file, but I'm getting this error. The servlet already has the @MultipartConfig notation. I'm using servlet 3.0 and apache tomcat 8.

Error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

on line

```
Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();`
```

Comment: Show us the servlet. Show us the full stack trace.

Comment: With Tomcat 8.5 and Servlet 3.1 annotation `@javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig` above servlet is enough for me to make it working

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had to add

```
allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"
```

on context tag inside context.xml

Comment: where is the context.xml file?

Comment: You should put it into the webapp's <Context> element of Webapp context.xml or or Tomcat's server.xml:

<Context ... allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">

Comment: You should put it into `MyProject/Web Pages/META-INF/context.xml`