# Java servlet Upload new File to server

Tags: java, file, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

can't read the Part :

my code :

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("PdfFile");



out.print(filePart.getSize()+"");
```

the error :

*Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578680/error-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration-has-been-provided

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Apache Commons Fileupload:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: This is unnecessary since 2009. Moreover, the question already shows new approach. Please catch up.

Answer (score -1):

Define a multipart resolver like this in your context file

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates OP is using Spring. Recommending to install a whole 3rd party framework just because the OP couldn't figure out how to use a standard API method makes no utter sense.